# Can I re-enter the US under VWP after my J-1 visa expires?

Tags: visas, usa, uk-citizens, j1-visas, us-visa-waiver-program

This summer I will be in the US on a J-1 visa program, and will be there for a few weeks after the program ends (as I have a 30 day window to leave). I then plan to be in Canada for a few days, and spend the next 23 days in the US, before returning to the UK. Would I be able to come back in on an ESTA?

If not, what are my options?

I am a British citizen, studying as an undergraduate in the UK at present.

Comment: Does your visa show the 2-year exclusion?

Comment: Are you planning to re-enter by land or by air? (You don't need an ESTA to enter by land.)

Comment: I will be re-entering by air, and my visa does not show the 2 year exclusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [two-year rule](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/study-exchange/exchange.html) means that you have to be physically present outside the US for a minimum total of two years before you can obtain H, L or K Status, or become a permanent resident, be it by means of a visa obtained at an embassy or change of status through the USCIS.

It does **not** prevent you from entering the US as a visitor under the VWP. In other words, although you are apparently not subject to the 2-year rule, even if you were you would be able to visit.