# Re-enter US on VWP from Canada after J1 expired as UK citizen

Tags: customs-and-immigration, esta, j1-visas

I am about to finish my internship under the J1 visa, but I would like to spend the summer travelling through the U.S for longer than the grace period of 30 days would allow me to. 
I have family who are Canadian citizens and was intending on flying up to Vancouver for a weekend when my grace period is over and then re-enter under the VWP. 
I know that ESTA does not guarantee me entry and it is eventually at the discretion of the IO at the POI, but I wanted to ask whether anyone has actually done this in the past and whether it worked or whether they got turned away.

All I could find online was a lot of assumptions and conflicting advice, but no actual experiences, so I would be grateful if someone could share if they have attempted this.

I will have a return ticket and I have a confirmed and accepted place for further study in my home country starting within a week after I intend to leave the US. I am also not returning to the city I had my J1 placement in, but a different one. I also have proof of sufficient funds and by the point of re-entry would have a travel itinerary with hotel bookings.

Thanks

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66223/can-i-re-enter-the-us-under-vwp-after-my-j-1-visa-expires?rq=1 How will one data point provided by one person help you? You're asking for information from a sample whose size will be very small i.e. J1's who exited to Canada post graduation and tried to enter on VWP using an ESTA. You may or may not be allowed back in and I will give a 85% odds against being allowed in. Make it 93% upon reconsideration

Comment: I simply wanted to see whether someone has actually been turned away under these circumstances or could re-enter after finishing J1, exiting US and seeking to return as a tourist for 2 months with return tickets and travel itinerary etc. what do you base your 93% odds on if I may ask?

Comment: Being someone who went from B1/B2 through F to H1B through permanent residency to citizenship and in the immigration pipeline for close to twenty years, I've lived through all and heard it all (almost). Your chances are very very slim indeed and I only pegged it at 93% because almost nothing in this world has 100% probability.